# How do I code this in VBA for my Excel Macro

Tags: excel, vba

How do I code my Excel to be in VBA?  Starting at the right of `Target.Offset(0, -4).Value =`
I don't know how to say this in VBA: `(Text(TODAY(), "MM") & Text(TODAY(), "DD") & Text(TODAY(), "yyyy")) & "-" . iVal`

This is for auto-incrimination for records based on date. Here is the entire code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Column = 6 Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Target.Offset(0, 2).Value = Date
    Target.Offset(0, 4).Value = "Open"


Dim iVal As Integer
iVal = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("H1:H5000"), Date)
    Target.Offset(0, -4).Value = (Text(TODAY(), "MM") & Text(TODAY(), "DD") & Text(TODAY(), "yyyy")) & "-" . iVal

    Application.EnableEvents = True
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: If you ever dont know the syntax or need quick vba help remember you can record a macro using relative referencing and see what code is generated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hows this work for you.... i am assuming columns

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Column = 6 Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Target.Offset(0, 2).Value = Date
    Target.Offset(0, 4).Value = "Open"


**Dim iVal As Integer
iVal = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("H1:H5000"), Date)
    Target.Offset(0, -4).Value = Format(Date, "mmddyy") & "-" & Format(iVal, "000")**

    Application.EnableEvents = True
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

the function for formatted text is FORMAT and the function for today() is Date.
Examples as follow:

```
format(Date,"ddmmyyyy")
```

This should solve your problem =]
And I think you mean

```
& iVal
```

istead of

```
. iVal
```

at the end?